# Listify a number

Tags: code-golf, number

Given a real number, convert it to a list of lists, with the negative sign (if any) becoming an empty list, the integer part becoming a list of digits, and the fractional part (if any) becoming a list of digits. The digits must be actual numbers, not strings.

#### Examples

`0` → `[[0]]`

`123` → `[[1,2,3]]`

`-123` → `[[],[1,2,3]]`

`123.45` → `[[1,2,3],[4,5]]`

`0.45` → `[[0],[4,5]]`

`-0.45` → `[[],[0],[4,5]]`

`-123.45` → `[[],[1,2,3],[4,5]]`

Comment: are the digits in the array allowed to be single-char strings?

Comment: @dzaima No. I'll add that.

Comment: can the number be taken as a string?

Comment: @Uriel If you get input from STDIN then yes (there is no difference). If as argument, no, I think. Whatever Meta consensus is.

Comment: If the whole part is zero can we use an empty list?

Comment: @WheatWizard No, that would create an ambiguity between `0.45` and `-45`.

Comment: Will there be input such as `.45` or `-.45`?

Comment: @StepHen The input will be a number in whatever format your language uses (for results).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any context or motivation to this question?

Comment: @Quelklef Yes, in fact. It was the result of a long design discussion [you can see here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39054011#39054011) about the `l` (listify) command of [totallyhuman](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/280050/totallyhuman)'s WIP language, [Intrnt](https://github.com/totallyhuman/intrnt).

Answer (score 7):

## C#, <s>60</s> 66 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>s.Split('-','.').Select(p=>p.Select(c=>c-48))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNSwMxEL3nVwy5bEKzoWoFod1cioqiIPTQQ@khplMNbJO6kxWk9Lev6ad68/Lmg3mPec9RuYohdi358AaTL0q4GrLfk37y4WPImKstEbywDaNkk3fwGf0Cnq0PQublXRvciFKTiepIHMe6Rpd8DKTvMWDjnX64De0KG/ta4@ifZz4kYwwsoYKOKkN6sq59EkVZqEIXUk9wRxfryqxPvauMKwc3Unb58UVss8xsDgkpjS0hZaUN9BVcXF4pKPeYQQ@uFfT3WB7LYQvbIVvGBq17B3FQO2uBDz@6ko2ziVijnjY@YQ4OBZ9x6MEhmGw1OJvEUpzpPeD8bMFCZeAP4THmeLniCqzc3c65PNXsbMu23Tc)

Comment: There are no visible outer brackets. Are your results actually lists?

Comment: @Adám Yeah (`IEnumerable<char[]>`) it's just the printing code doesn't add them in.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The requirements state that the required return type is a list of digits as numbers, not strings or chars which display those numbers.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Oh didn't see the spec had been updated...

Comment: @KamilDrakari Fixed, thanks for letting me know about the update.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

Takes input as a string. Sacrificed <s>11</s> 10 bytes converting the elements in the output to numbers after the challenge spec was updated.

```
s=>s.split(/\D/).map(a=>[...a].map(eval))
```

- Saved a byte thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s suggestion of using  `eval`.

---

### Test it

```js
console.log((
s=>s.split(/\D/).map(a=>[...a].map(eval))
)("-123.45"))
```

---

### Explanation

```
s=>
```

Anonymous function taking the string as an argument via parameter `s`.
`"-123.45"`

```
s.split(/\D/)
```

Use RegEx to split the string to an array on all non-digit characters - i.e., `-` and `.`
`["","123","45"]`

```
.map(a=>)
```

Map over the array, passing each string to a function via parameter `a`.

```
[...a]
```

Split to an array of individual character strings.
`[[],["1","2","3"],["4","5"]]`

```
.map(eval)
```

Map over the subarray and `eval` each string, which converts it to an integer.
`[[],[1,2,3],[4,5]]`

Comment: 2D array of strings? How does the JSON look?

Comment: Digits must be numbers.

Comment: @Adám: Updated, at a cost of 11 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒṘµ<”/œpV€
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning the resulting list of lists of numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7ZxzaavOoYa7@0ckFYY@a1vw/3A4W/f9fV8/EFAA)** (the footer just prints the python representation to show all the actual lists)
...or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7ZxzaavOoYa7@0ckFYY@a1vw/uudwO1hcBcjLAuJHDXMUdO0UgGoi//@PNtBRMDQy1lHQBZNAQs/EVEcBTOhCSIhYLAA).

#### How?

```
ŒṘµ<”/œpV€ - Link: number
ŒṘ         - Python representation (yields a string representation of the number)
  µ        - monadic chain separation (call that s)
    ”/     - literal '/' character
   <       - less than? (vectorises) ('.' and '-' are, digit characters are not)
      œp   - partition s at truthy indexes of the resulting list discarding the borders
        V€ - evaluate €ach (list of characters) as Jelly code (vectorises)
```

Comment: And again Jelly is better than 05AB1E!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda x:[map(int,i)for i in`x`.replace(*'-.').split('.')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEEDRq7hzJkooaBN0kgqyUhpQG8ygTm/u/uJ9/tJ5hS7bcc5O@@3Q4h0mrxkopJrQXlGQoLC@q4qGnd4NVLJREtXNjhLIkkvmWDjYMvGTABFz06r@Bw)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Thanks to *Riley* for saving a byte. Code:

```
'-'.:'.¡εSï
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXVddz0pd79DCc1uDD6///1/X0MhYz8QUAA)

Explanation:

```
'-'.:            # Replace "-" by "."
     '.¡         # Split on "."
        ε        # Apply to each element..
         S       #   Split into a list of characters
          ï      #   Convert back to int
```

Comment: Do you technically need the `ï`?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn OP said `The digits must be actual numbers, not strings.`

Comment: That's a shame, I was thinking: `„-.S€¡` for 6, but if they have to be ints... unsure.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda a:[[]]*(a<0)+[map(int,n)for n in`abs(a)`.split('.')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwEETvfsXe2FVsFOVC9EtKE5ZoYxNYGroXv74UvbzM5E0mfvWzSJP9s88Tz@OLgTtrnTsiPy50sjNHDKK1kF9WEAgy8JiQaTApTkGxMhW5vEt9Jy0e8Nrcajj/WGDu7b@VQN0BIK7lED3ue6K8AQ)

-5 bytes from Felipe Nardi Batista

Comment: in your third output `[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]]` there is an extra outer list

Comment: fixed and still uses 64 bytes [link](https://tio.run/##LYzBDoIwEETvfsXe2NXSKOql0S9BEpZoYxNYGroXv74U9fIyM5mZ@NH3LE3290ceeRqeDOzatuv2yLcjHSaO@M/FbSaIGiHT85CQqbcpjkGxshVR9vMC@koKQQBPzdlA/WWBvVx/rghyO4C4lCf0uPXLdAU)

Comment: you can get to 59 bytes if you change your outer `map` with list comprehension: [link](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwEETvfsXe2FVsFOVC9EtKE5ZoYxNYGroXv74UvbzM5E0mfvWzSJP9s88Tz@OLgTtrnTsiPy50sjNHDKK1kF9WEAgy8JiQaTApTkGxMhW5vEt9Jy0e8Nrcajj/WGDu7b@VQN0BIK7lED3ue6K8AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 23 bytes

```
'.@;)A$s⌠♂≈⌡M[[]]+@s~@t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/19dz8Fa01Gl@FHPgkczmx51djzqWegbHR0bq@1QXOdQ8v@/rqGRsZ6JqRkA)

Explanation:

```
'.@;)A$s⌠♂≈⌡M[[]]+@s~@t
'.                       push "."
  @;)                    make a copy of the input and move it to the bottom of the stack
     A$s                 absolute value of input, stringify, split on periods
        ⌠♂≈⌡M            convert integer and fractional parts to lists of digits
             [[]]+       prepend an empty list
                  @s~    bitwise negation of sign of input (1 -> -2, 0 -> -1, -1 -> 0)
                     @t  elements in the list starting at that 0-based index (drops the leading empty list if the input was positive)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
Ζ-.ŗ .Θ⌡č¹r
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMzk2LS4ldTAxNTclMjAuJXUwMzk4JXUyMzIxJXUwMTBEJUI5cg__,inputs=LTEyMy40NTY_)

Outputs to the top of the stack (because SOGL converts it to a multiline string because it is made for ascii-art). To view the result, look in the console after  `` `r`@10: `` (the outer brackets are the stack arrays) or just append `οø∑` after the code

```
Ζ-.ŗ         replace "-" with "."
     .Θ      split on "."s
       ⌡     for each
        č      chop into characters (casts to strings :/)
         ¹   wrap in array (this + for each is like map())
          r  reverse types, vectorizing
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) (v2.0a0), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```
q\D ®¬®n
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=cVxEIK6srm4=&input=Ii0xMjMuNDUiCi1R) (`-Q` flag for visualisation purposes only.)

- 2 bytes saved thanks to [Justin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner).
- 2 bytes saved thanks to ETH.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U`.

```
q\D
```

Use RegEx to split (`q`) to an array on all non-digit characters.

```
®
```

Map over the array.

```
¬
```

Split each string to an array of individual characters.

```
®
```

Map over the array.

```
n
```

Convert to integer.

Comment: Couldn't you split on `\D`, since the only non-digits will be `.` and `-`?

Comment: The best part is, you don't even need the `/`s :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions: Now, that's pretty sweet. I thought I might have been able to omit the closing `/` by going multiline. I never considered trying to omit both of them.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 54 bytes

```matlab
@(x)cellfun(@(c){c-48},strsplit(num2str(x),{'-' '.'}))
```

Anonymous function that takes a number as input and produces a cell array of numeric vectors.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjQjM5NScnrTRPw0EjWbM6WdfEolanuKSouCAns0QjrzTXCMgBqtKpVtdVV1DXU6/V1PyfpqFraGSsZ2Kq@R8A)

#### Explanation

```matlab
@(x)cellfun(@(c){c-48},strsplit(num2str(x),{'-' '.'}))

@(x)                                                    % Function with input x
                                num2str(x)              % Convert x to string
                       strsplit(          ,{'-' '.'})   % Split at '-' or '.'. Gives a
                                                        % cell array of substrings
    cellfun(          ,                               ) % To each substring apply
                                                        % the following function
            @(c){c-48}                                  % Subtract 48 from each char
                                                        % and pack into a cell
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>170</s> <s>164</s> <s>152</s> <s>146</s> 144 bytes

Should be able to golf this down a bit...

```c
#define P printf
#define V *v[1]
main(c,v)char**v;{for(V^45?P("[[%c",V++):P("[[],[%c",V++,V++);V;V^46?P(",%c",V++):P("],[%c",V++,V++));P("]]");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIUChoCgzrySNCyYQpqBVFm0Yy5WbmJmnkaxTppmckVikpVVmXZ2WX6QRFmdiah@goRQdrZqspBOmra1pBebF6sAEwILWYdZAlWYglTrICtGUaVqDxGKVNK1r////r2toZKxnYgoA)

Comment: I think you can save a few bytes by doing `#define P printf(` and then omitting the parenthesis in the `P` calls

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒṘ⁾-.yṣ”.V€€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7Zzxq3KerV/lw5@JHDXP1wh41rQGi/4fbwXL//@sa6pkCAA)

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, currently I've only got 13 (I'll post that but think it must be able to be shorter) `0.45` returns `[[],[4,5]` instead of `[[0],[4,5]]` (it collides with `-45`)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh yeah indeed...not sure where I got that? Oh wait, it's `Ṿ`! Fixing...ok fixed. Who would expect that Jelly parses the `0` and `.45` of `0.45` separately...and have it as `Ṿ` output too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

```
$'.'-(Æ'.@s⌠♂≈⌡M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/19FXU9dV@Nwm7qeQ/GjngWPZjY96ux41LPQ9/9/XQM9E1MA)

Explanation:

```
$'.'-(Æ'.@s⌠♂≈⌡M Implicit eval'd input
$                Convert to str
 '.              Push '.'
   '-            Push '-'
     (           Rotate stack left
      Æ          Pop a, b, c; push c.replace(b, a)
       '.        Push '.'
         @       Pop a, b; push b, a (swap)
          ⌠♂≈⌡   Push function ♂≈
           ♂       Map
            ≈        Convert to int
              M  Map
```

Comment: Outgolfed the creator, nice.

Comment: @Zacharý It's just a matter of algorithm choice.

Comment: And it's Mego you beat, not Dennis of course :)

Comment: @Zacharý Well, twice in this challenge to be fair...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <strike>56</strike> 54 + 1 (-p) = 55 bytes

```perl
$_="[[$_]]";s/\D\K\./0./;s/\d(?=\d)/$&,/g;s/-|\./],[/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYpOlolPjZWybpYP8YlxjtGT99ATx/ESdGwt41J0dRXUdPRTwcK6NYA5WJ1ovXT///XNTQy1jMx/ZdfUJKZn1f8X7cAAA)

*Saved two bytes due to Dom reminding me about $&*

**Explanation:**

```perl
$_="[[$_]]";        # Add opening and closing to ends of strings
s/\D\K\./0./;       # handle the case of .45 or -.45 by inserting 0 before
                    # the decimal.  Otherwise, .45 & 45 would be ambiguous.
s/\d(?=\d)/$&,/g;   # Put a comma between numbers.
s/-|\./],[/g        # Turn - and . into separators between lists
```

Comment: Had a little play with this and found breaking it down to be a bit shorter. Not sure if you can combine it based on mine to shrink yours down?  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX7cmRk8/VidaP926WD8mRcPeNiZFU19FTQcooBJvqxQdrRIfG6v0/78hl6GRMZcuhOAy1APTINJAz9CISxdE/ssvKMnMzyv@r1uQAwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Used $& from yours.  I think the two are basically equivalent now, except that mine handles the ".45" vs. "45" case.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>51</s> <s>47</s> 72 bytes

```
x=RG::s(strtoi(s(gsub('-','.',scan()),on='\\.')))
x[is.na(x)]=list(NULL)
```

I'm loving the `RG` library.

Had to add 26 bytes to make sure the empty list was actually empty.

```
               gsub('-','.',scan())             # replace - with . in input; also converts to string
             s(                    ,on='\\.')   # split string on '.'
      strtoi(                                )  # convert to numeric
RG::s(                                        ) # convert to lists of digits

    x[is.na(x)]=list(NULL)                      # converts list of `NA` to empty list
```

Example output:

```
> x=RG::s(strtoi(s(gsub('-','.',-123.45),on='\\.')))
> x[is.na(x)]=list(NULL)
> x
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5
```

Comment: well, there's `numeric(0)` for an empty numeric list or `list()` or `NULL`?

Comment: I tacked on a fix to make it `NULL` but now I'm sure there's a golfier way to do it. Maybe I'll come back to it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
+«*.split(/\D/)».comb
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VZFNbsIwEIX3PsUItcUGx4R/CSuoiy677C5kkSaDFOEQizioUdUT9QjdcbHU@SHAbvy9p2e/scaTWlVFjnBeiUiStISXKIsRvGp8@R2JXKvE0MnubcIufyLK0s@qMb0azA14QAmAC94WfN8NeMDtcTqbt2DKZ3zeQaenAe@Eq1kslg9@f8GXrej2knuPnRu3@FG6z@tv6g1Mkrrqh327JFqFRxg3RSTZZ6euk7MFCpsDlvQpOerCMA6bc6gKpI3OgMG3vcnuYIdfGiODsd1Do4k01HQk3hM7JgZT1ozSupPciRG1KqFe7i35msBhANBSsU8NHT6v8yGra7TB2n4TZQPyU/0D)

### Expanded

```perl6
+«\            # numify each of the following (possibly in parallel)
*\             # WhateverCode lambda (this is the input)
.split(/\D/)\  # split on non-digits ( . and - )
».comb         # split each of those into individual characters
```

Note that `…».comb` is a higher precedence than `+«…`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda x:(x<0)*[[]]+[map(int,i)for i in`abs(x)`.split('.')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoMgEAXv@xV7E1ok1NaLqV9CScQ0pJsoEuVAvx7R9jKTvMO88I2fxTfZ9a882Xl8W0wdS0/FL1obc9WzDYx8FMTdsiIh@cGOG0t8kFuYKLJKVtxk6rUScGvuAuqTBfLRClAn679@q4GjlUoLqQMMazlAV5qIeQc)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 13 bytes

```
r'-'.er'./::~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v0hdV10vtUhdT9/Kqu5/wn9dAz0TUwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

```
sMMcXz\-\.\.
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sMMcXz%5C-%5C.%5C.&input=-0.45&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

```
{m:g/^\d*|\d+/».comb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtcqXT8uJkWrJiZFW//Qbr3k/Nyk2v/WCsWJlQpKKvEKtnYK1WkaKvGaeumZxSW1Sgpp@UUKNgYKhkbGCrogAoj1TEwVDECELoSECNlZ/wcA)

The elements in the returned list are strings, but as is normal for Perl, they can be used as numbers and will be converted implicitly; they are "actual numbers" for all practical purposes.  To force them to be numbers in their most immediate representation, one need only prefix the contents of the code block with "+«" for three more bytes.

Comment: The challenge specifically states “*The digits must be actual numbers, not strings.*”, so the `+«` should probably be included.

Answer (score 0):

## RUBY, 75 bytes

```
->(x){(x<0?[[]]:[])+x.abs.to_s.split('.').map{|y|y.chars.map{|z|z.to_i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vYzLCgIhGIX3PkW7UWJ@7LaJLg8iEo5MJVjJ6IDO6LNb5itEi/PBuXCGsQs562N7wp7M2B/omTHO94yTpQfRWXCviwVrtHK4gYbAQ5g5hhhA3sVgq53iVHYqpZTN6OxCgxRa41vvvgeKgHpa00uHfl9f/1NnilbrDWoLPoLtDtGCtrJGbw)

Comment: Can you remove all that whitespace?

Comment: Yep, you're right, done!

Comment: The same with some syntax tweaks: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfo2D7X9euolqjwsbAPjo6NtYqOlZTu0IvMalYryQ/vlivuCAns0TDXk9TLzexoLqmsqZSLzkjsagYxFVQswKqyayt/V9QWlKskKOXnJiTo5GeWgLWm6mpl5lXXJCaXMJFfek0@kj/N@AyNDLm0gURQKxnYsplACJ0ISRECAA "Ruby – Try It Online") (BTW, if you use Header and Footer on TIO the size displayed on the right side of Code will be the actual size of the solution.)

Comment: Fixed, thanks for all the infos.

Comment: You can swap `.map{z|z.to_i}` for `.map &:to_i`